# Post form via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm working on my first php project and I appear to have hit a milesone, I'm trying to get my form to post via javascript so that the webpage does not have to refresh but I cannot see to get it to work, any help appreciated :)

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function say(){
var theusername = $("#message").val();
    $.post("q3/say.php", {
    message: message,
    }
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<form><input type="text" name="message"><input type=BUTTON value="Submit" onClick="say()"></form>
```

Comment: It's called AJAX and there are plenty of tutorials out there. Besides, you need to include what doesn't work / what errors you are getting.

Comment: [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't closed properly curly braces and there is no need for return false as you already use `type="button"` on form.  See below code :

```js
function say(){
  
    var theusername = $("#message").val();
  
    $.post("q3/say.php", { message: theusername }, function ( data ) {
       // populate data here
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="message">
  <input type=BUTTON value="Submit" onClick="say()">
</form>
```

You might need to read this [**POST**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). The callback function is optional in case you want to populate or doing something after request being made

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I've used that code and now the form is submitting but the variables aren't getting passed through, like the $message variable, Any ideas?

Comment: Cause you doesn't have element with id  `#message` in your html. Use this `<input type="text" name="message" id="message">`